# A type of coupling problem I

Tags: measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

This posting is related to a recent question asked in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4640948/121671): Suppose $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space. If $\nu$ is another measure on $\mathscr{B}$, $\nu(X)=\mu(X)$,  and $\nu\ll\mu$,  is there a measurable map $T:(X,\mathscr{B})\rightarrow(X,\mathscr{B})$ such that $\nu=\mu\circ T^{-1}$?  (Here $\mu\circ T^{-1}$ is the push-forward of $\mu$ by $T$, that is $(\mu\circ T^{-1})(A):=\mu(T^{-1}(A))$).

The answer is yes for Borel spaces $X$ when $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ is isomorphic to the standard Lebesgue space $((0,1),\mathscr{B}((0,1)),\lambda)$ ( $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure restricted to the unit interval with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) regardless of whether $\nu\ll\mu$ or not. Indeed, on the standard Lebesgue space, one  can use the quantile function $Q_\nu(q):=\inf\{x: \nu(0,x]\geq q\}$ to get $\nu=\lambda\circ Q^{-1}$.

My question is whether the statement holds another measure $\mu$
on  $((0,1),\mathscr{B}(0,1))$ that is not equivalent to $\lambda$ (i.e. either $\mu\not\ll\lambda$ or $\lambda\not\ll\mu$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\de\delta$The answer to your first question is no.

E.g., let $\mu:=2\de_{1/3}+2\de_{2/3}$ and $\nu:=\de_{1/3}+3\de_{2/3}$, where $\de_a$ is the Dirac measure with support $\{a\}$. Then all the conditions imposed on $\mu$ and $\nu$ hold. However, $\nu(\{1/3\})=1$ is an odd integer, whereas all the values of the measure $\mu$ are even integers. So, $\nu\ne\mu T^{-1}$ for any $T$.

---

MO posts should not have multiple questions. So, I suggest you post the other two questions separately.

Comment: @OliverDíaz : Your post still contains two questions, which are actually very different from each other (and, in fact, you seem to just -- essentially -- have combined the 2nd and 3rd questions into one). I think the answer to your second question is yes --but, again, it should be posted separately.

Comment: @OliverDíaz : You still have two questions in one post. The two questions clearly require very different approaches, with probably two different answers. Also, the second question is not clearly delineated. So, I still suggest that you post the second question separately, in a specific form.

Comment: I just posted a related [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/441285/78591) following your suggestion. Thanks!