# A type of coupling problem II

Tags: measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

This posting is related the following questions in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4640948/121671) and in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/441128/78591).

In general terms,  suppose $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space. If $\nu$ is another measure on $\mathscr{B}$, $\nu(X)=\mu(X)$,  and $\nu\ll\mu$,  is there a measurable map $T:(X,\mathscr{B})\rightarrow(X,\mathscr{B})$ such that $\nu=\mu\circ T^{-1}$?  (Here $\mu\circ T^{-1}$ is the push-forward of $\mu$ by $T$, that is $(\mu\circ T^{-1})(A):=\mu(T^{-1}(A))$).

As noted in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4640948/121671), the answer is yes for Borel spaces $X$ when $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ is isomorphic to the standard Lebesgue space $((0,1),\mathscr{B}((0,1)),\lambda)$, regardless of whether $\nu\ll\mu$ or not. This  can be achieved by the  use  the quantile function $Q_\nu(q):=\inf\{x: \nu(0,x]\geq q\}$ to get $\nu=\lambda\circ Q^{-1}$.

The uniform distribution $\lambda$ (or any equivalent measure to $\lambda$ on $((0,1),\mathcal{B}(0,1)))$ is special in this way, that is  any other measure $\nu$ on $((0,1),\mathcal{B}(0,1))$ can be expressed as a pushforward of $\lambda$.
This [posting](https://mathoverflow.net/q/441128/78591) gives a  counter example where  where $\mu$ is not equivalent to $\lambda$,  $\nu\ll\mu$ and yet $\nu$ is not a pushforward of $\mu$.

The question I have now whether uniformity in other settings have the property that the Lebesgue measure has. For example, consider a (compact) manifold $M$ of dimension $m$  embedded on Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{B}(M)$ inherited from the Euclidean space,  and the measure $\mu$ being the $m$-dimensional (normalized) Hausdorff measure $H^m$ on $(M,\mathscr{B}(M))$. Can any other measure $\nu$ ($\nu\ll H^m$ perhaps?) be expressed a the pushforward of $H^m$ by a measurable map $T:(M,\mathscr{B}(M))\rightarrow(M,\mathscr{B}(M))$?

Comment: What do you mean by a normalized $H^{m}$ measure? It does not need to be even finite (i.e. $sin(1/x)$).

Comment: My impression is that every diffuse (i.e. without atom) finite measure on a Polish space has the same property (providing every measure with same mass by suitable push-forward), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space

Comment: @Asaf: For example, the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, its length element is the Hausdorff measure $H^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ restricted to $\mathbb{S}^1$  (or a constant multiple of it); the surface area element  of the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is (a constant multiple) of $H^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ restricted to $\mathbb{S}^2$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz, I know that there are examples where $H^{m}$ is finite, but sometimes it is infinite or zero...

Comment: @Asaf: It does not matter if the total mass $\mu(M)$ (volume element of the manifold at $M$) is infinity, as long as $\nu(M)=\mu(M)$ and possibly $\nu\ll\mu$, can a pushforward can be construct. The manifold can be assume compact and smooth to make things easier.